# Add space on existing ext4 ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have ubuntu 13.10 installation on a 30Gb ext4 partition dual booting with windows 7 taking the rest of the disk space of 320Gb HD.

My ubuntu partition is full and I get 'no space left' error on which i've been deleting few  user files to free up the memory and continue using it. This cannot continue forever. So, I have come up with two options to for fixing this:

1) Shrink a windows partition and extend the ext4 partition with the unallocated space obtained by shrinking win7 parttion. How to do this??

2) Re-partition and make clean ubuntu installation.

However, i don't want to make clean installation. So, i want some guide for option-1 or if there is better option to do this without affecting ubuntu installation, that'll be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can do the 1st option without affecting your ext4 partition.It's better if you upload gparted screenshot to imgur.com and provide the link here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [ubuntu wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions) on this topic. In short, you can use either the Windows 7 tools to resize the windows partition or gparted, then you use gparted to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition.

It's recommended that you back up your data as partition / filesystem resizing is a potentially destructive operation.

Comment: is it necessary to defrag ntfs before resizing..i have about 50gb free space in my ntfs partition..but windows is allowing me to shrink only 6gb.

Comment: On the bottom of [the page I linked](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions#Problems) there is a discussion about the Master File Table preventing you from resizing an NTFS partition. This is a Windows 7 thing and there's not much you can do about it. Defragging won't hurt but I don't think it will solve your problem.